PHP open file url is not working (I use pdf js for pdf view only)
<script src="https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.mjs" type="module"></script>
    <script type='module'>
                      // If absolute URL from the remote server is provided, configure the CORS
                      // header on that server.
                      var url = <?php'$fileUrl';?>

                      // Loaded via script> tag, create shortcut to access PDF.js exports.
                      var { pdfjsLib } = globalThis;

                      // The workerSrc property shall be specified.
                      pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 'https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.mjs';

                      var pdfDoc = null,
                          pageNum = 1,
                          pageRendering = false,
                          pageNumPending = null,
                          scale = 0.8,
                          canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas'),
                          ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

                      /**
                       * Get page info from document, resize canvas accordingly, and render page.
                       * @param num Page number.
                       */
                      function renderPage(num) {
                        pageRendering = true;
                        // Using promise to fetch the page
                        pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(function(page) {
                          var viewport = page.getViewport({scale: scale});
                          canvas.height = viewport.height;
                          canvas.width = viewport.width;

                          // Render PDF page into canvas context
                          var renderContext = {
                            canvasContext: ctx,
                            viewport: viewport
                          };
                          var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);

                          // Wait for rendering to finish
                          renderTask.promise.then(function() {
                            pageRendering = false;
                            if (pageNumPending !== null) {
                              // New page rendering is pending
                              renderPage(pageNumPending);
                              pageNumPending = null;
                            }
                          });
                        });

                        // Update page counters
                        document.getElementById('page_num').textContent = num;
                      }

                      /**
                       * If another page rendering in progress, waits until the rendering is
                       * finised. Otherwise, executes rendering immediately.
                       */
                      function queueRenderPage(num) {
                        if (pageRendering) {
                          pageNumPending = num;
                        } else {
                          renderPage(num);
                        }
                      }

                      /**
                       * Displays previous page.
                       */
                      function onPrevPage() {
                        if (pageNum <= 1) {
                          return;
                        }
                        pageNum--;
                        queueRenderPage(pageNum);
                      }
                      document.getElementById('prev').addEventListener('click', onPrevPage);

                      /**
                       * Displays next page.
                       */
                      function onNextPage() {
                        if (pageNum >= pdfDoc.numPages) {
                          return;
                        }
                        pageNum++;
                        queueRenderPage(pageNum);
                      }
                      document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click', onNextPage);

                      /**
                       * Asynchronously downloads PDF.
                       */
                      pdfjsLib.getDocument(url).promise.then(function(pdfDoc_) {
                        pdfDoc = pdfDoc_;
                        document.getElementById('page_count').textContent = pdfDoc.numPages;

                        // Initial/first page rendering
                        renderPage(pageNum);
                      });
                    </script>
  
<?php
// Function to trim the extension from a filename
function trimExtension($filename) {
    // Check if the filename has a dot indicating an extension
    if (strpos($filename, '.') !== false) {
        // Remove everything after and including the last dot
        $filename = substr($filename, 0, strrpos($filename, '.'));
    }
    return $filename;
}

// Directory containing the files
$directory = "POLICY/"; // Change this to your folder path

echo "<table>
        <tr>
            <th>Serial No.</th>
            <th>Filename</th>
            <th>File URL</th>
        </tr>";

// Open the directory
if ($handle = opendir($directory)) {
    $serialNumber = 1; // Initialize serial number
    // Loop over all the files in the directory
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) 
    {
        // Skip the current and parent directory entries
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") 
        {
            // Trim the extension from the filename
            $trimmedFilename = trimExtension($file);
            // Convert filename to uppercase
            $upperFilename = strtoupper($trimmedFilename);
            $fileUrl = $directory . '/' . $file;
            echo "<tr>
                    <td>$serialNumber</td>
                    <td>$upperFilename</td>
                    <td><a href= "?> 
                    <canvas id='the-canvas'></canvas>

                    
                    
                    <?php echo "Open File</a></td>
                  </tr>";
            $serialNumber++; // Increment serial number
        }
    }

    echo "</table>";

    // Close the directory handle
    closedir($handle);
} else {
    echo "Failed to open directory.";
}
?>

I want open file link option working. As while clicking on open file option it redirects to itself or redirects to something canvas. I tried using button click or renderpdf function but that is also not working. I have write these code to open pdf file in  only view option not to download or print option enabled using java scrip.

<?php'$fileUrl';?> doesn't do anything. That should be '<?php echo $fileUrl;?>'

You should have gotten a syntax error in the JavaScript console for that.

when I use the above js code to open pdf file from specific location, it opens the pdf file in browser to only view pages but user not able to downloaded or print that pdf.
